# Bluetooth Modules in a plastic enclosure

Tags: design, bluetooth, antenna, enclosure

I would like to implement a bluetooth functionality in my project, preferably using STMicroelectronics SPBT2632C1A.AT2, with a protective enclosure. But I read from multiple sources that bluetooth antennas get detuned if they are surrounded by a plastic material.

My question is, are these bluetooth modules (like the one I mentioned above) subjected to the same problem? Would the attenuation be too much to the point that the communication would become unstable? My application requires fast (500k baud) and reliable communication within a few feet. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally with an RF application, you want to tune higher or lower than the frequency you are trying to broadcast. Th surrounding material attenuation then matches with the proper operating frequency. In this case you can not do that, so the range will drop. I believe you will still be fine for a few feet of range after looking at the datasheet and seeing you can crank it to 10 dBm. This also depends on the thickness of the case material however.

If you can find a module (or want to make one) with external filter components then you can switch these out and tune according to the case. Hope this helps.